# Sample star schema dataset

Tags: database, sample, star-schema

I'm looking for some OLAP data preferably in star schema (or snowflake) for testing a new tool. I've already got the Foodmart database that Mondrian provides. Type of data is not important as long as it has dimensions and associated facts. The larger the size the better for load testing. Anybody knows where I can download such a dataset, ideally in SQL or CSV? (other formats are fine too)

Comment: Isn't this the sort of thing you'd... google yourself?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apologies for being MS SQL focussed, but the [Adventure Works DWH](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms124623.aspx) is not bad as far as an snowflake schema design. Not not huge as far as data volumes. With some clever SQL you would be able to generate extra rows in the database.

Alternatively try [Project Real](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966416.aspx) - a larger DWH project that put together by MS on 2005

Comment: OnLine Transaction Processing is not the same as OnLine Analysis Processing. OLAP = lots of small simple queries, high percentage of updates. OLAP = few large complicated queries , batch update process.

Comment: ah @James Anderson, you say "OLAP = lots of small simple queries, high percentage of updates. OLAP = few large complicated queries , batch update process", I think you did the same as me, and got OLAP/OLTP mislabeled.